# Is RX.net subject thread safe for subscribers?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm having a hard time finding information as google yields results about the safety of concurrently pushing data to the subject, this isn't my use case, i have a dedicated thread (running an infinite loop) producing data, and i want N other threads to be able to subscribe to it.

1. Is it safe to call non-producing methods (subsribe/observe etc but not On*) methods on a Subject from another thread than the one who created it if i only push data into it from a single (who also happens to be the instance creating) thread?
2. In the case it is safe : is it safe at any time (could i subscribe from another thread while the primary one is in the middle on calling OnNext) or is it only safe if when i call Subscribe no data is being produced?
3. Same question as #2 but about multiple observers calling Subscribe at the same time to register if i have a dozen threads that need to register, is that also safe?

Comment: What is your definition of "safe" here? What would be your desired behavior and why can't you build a proof of concept around that?

Comment: @Fildor i can (and have) a working PoC, a PoC is not a validation and i couldn't easily find a formal answer, i'm not building a while system around "it worked in my PoC, crossing fingers it still will when i scale". And my definition of safe is the usual definition of thread safe, built expecting calls from other threads without risking corrupting the internal state and with well defined behavior

Comment: So with that definition, you know what _should_ break the code if it's _not_ thread safe, right? Also, you can inspect the implementation to be 100% sure.

Comment: @Fildor No i wouldn't know what should break the code if it's not thread safe, that's implementation specific. Yes i could read the implementation, i don't see myself reading up the whole RX implementation instead of just getting an answer here from someone who knows

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks! :) If you want to convert that in a reply i'll just accept it, if not i'll just copy/paste in in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these methods are thread safe. I don't think there is explicit documentation to that effect, but the most compelling, if not easily digestible evidence is the source code itself.

Take a look at the [implementation of Subscribe here](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/9fb0ed0d0160902ca550c44f6d2f89f54b0b53c7/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Subjects/Subject.cs#L163) to see plenty of evidence of use of thread safe techniques, such as use of `Interlocked` when updating the observers.

To avoid misleading any casual readers, I reiterate your observation that `OnNext` etc. methods are *not* thread safe by design, and use of the `Synchronize` method can help there if you really need them to be.

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed by @Enigmativity in comments subscribing is thread safe.

Will accept any answer instead of this one if someone provides something more detailed / official sources.